# How to add a where clause that looks for an array of values

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I was wondering if i could use an array for the below instead of writing multiple ORs

```
from d in db.tblEquipments.Include(t => t.User).Include(t => t.ChangeLog).AsEnumerable()
                                    where (d.AssetType == "Laptop" || d.AssetType == "Workstation" || d.AssetType == "Mobile" d.AssetType == "Monitor" d.AssetType == "Other Peripheral" || d.AssetType == "Home Printer" || d.AssetType == "Home Router" || d.AssetType == "Removable Device")
                                            (d.Active == 1) && 
                                            (d.Deleted != 1 || d.Deleted == null) &&
```

Something like the below?

```
string[] arrItems = new string[] { "Laptop", "Workstation", "Mobile" }; etc
where (d.assetType == arrItems) &&
         (d.Active == 1) && ....
```

is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Contains` method:

```
from d in db.tblEquipments.Include(t => t.User).Include(t => t.ChangeLog).AsEnumerable()
where arrItems.Contains(d.AssetType) &&  // same as SQL operator IN
      (d.Active == 1) && 
      (d.Deleted != 1 || d.Deleted == null) &&
```

Also don't use `AsEnumerable()` it brings all filtering into memory (i.e. instead of transferring only required equipments you are transferring all equipments over the network, and filter them in computer memory).

Comment: I would, however, change the order so you filter first on Active and Deleted before the Contains comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You have two ways to do it. The trivial way:

```
from d in myQueryable
where (arrItems.Contains(d.assetType)) &&
      (d.Active == 1) && ....
```

The problem with the previous method is that it checks all pair `(x in myEnumerable, y in arrItems)` which leads to a complexity of `O(n²)`

And the best way, with a complexity of `O(n)`:

```
from d in myQueryable
join arrItem in arrItems on d.AssetType equals arrItem
select d
```